# vb.net cannot update in oracle DB

Tags: vb.net, oracle

I am developing small program with VB.NET and Oracle DB. 
There is a problem when I want to update the column value.

This is my code:

```
  getOraConn()
  trans = ora_conn.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted)
    cmdOr.Transaction = trans
    Try
        cmdOr.CommandText = "update tbl_study set flag='0'"
        cmdOr.Connection = ora_conn
        cmdOr.ExecuteNonQuery()
        trans.Commit()
        ora_conn.Close()
        MessageBox.Show("sucess")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        trans.Rollback()

    End Try
```

When I running this code, it is always hangs at 'cmdOr.ExecuteNonQuery()' and then the column in DB still not change.

Here is my Oracle connection string:

```
 Function getOraConn() As OracleConnection

      Dim oradb As String = "Data Source=SPEC; User Id=sta;   Password=sta123;Pooling=False;"

    Try
        ora_conn = New OracleConnection(oradb)

        ora_conn.Open()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("connection failed", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
    End Try
End Function
```

Comment: Just to be clear, you're saying that if you debug and step through the code line by line, when you get to `cmdOr.ExecuteNonQuery()` and step to the next line, you never actually get to the next line, no matter how long you wait, correct?

Comment: @jmcilhinney yes,correct

Comment: By the way, that `getOraConn` method is pretty awful. I mean that you're using it at all, rather than how it's written.  It would be a far better idea to store your connection string in one place but create, open, use and close connection objects as and where they're needed. You should create, use and discard command objects and the like as needed to. I suggest that you check the examples [here](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?469872-Retrieving-and-Saving-Data-in-Databases). Only reuse objects if you have a specific reason to, e.g. retrieving and saving using the same data adapter.

Comment: I would suggest that you take my advice and create the connection and command there where you're using them and see if the same thing happens. It may be something that you have done elsewhere and that might make it hard to track down.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I already tried it. but the result still the same. fyi, I can select the table and get the value of the column

Comment: I'm not overly familiar with Oracle so I'm afraid I'm not sure what its vagaries might be but one thing to test at least is to specify a fairly short timeout period on your command object and see whether that gets `ExecuteNonQuery` to at least throw an exception on that timeout.

Comment: Also, if you tried what I suggested then please edit your question and show that code.  We can't be sure you did it right if we haven't seen it.

Comment: If your update is appearing to hang, you may well have a non-committed transaction waiting in another SQL session or client.

Comment: It looks like you need to use [Option Strict On](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement) as that will point out some problems, and possible fixes, in the code.

Comment: Your function doesn't return anything. So get rid of it.

Comment: thx u all for your answer. the error have been fixed. afte reinstall the oracle, the error miracle fixed.